# Error on python web page inport

Tags: python-3.x

i would like to request the information from this web page:
`https://centova.truckers.fm/rpc/truckersfm/streaminfo.get`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import urllib.request

 webpage = "https://centova.truckers.fm/rpc/truckersfm/streaminfo.get"

 websource = urllib.request.urlopen(webpage) soup =
 soup = BeautifulSoup(websource.read(), "html.parser")

 print (span)
```

Every time that the code is run i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Stuart/Desktop/discord bot/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    websource = urllib.request.urlopen(webpage)
  File "C:\Users\Stuart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Stuart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\Stuart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\Stuart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Stuart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Stuart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
>>>
```

does anyone know how to fix this

Comment: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden -> You need to authenticate yourself to the server providing the web page.

Comment: what do you mean by that as i open it on the web browser i can see it all

Comment: This can have different reasons: You have authenticated before in your browser and thus you can simply open the page. But your python script using BeautifulSoup never has authenticated and is therefore rejected by a 403. The other possibilityis that the webpage you want to scrape recognizes you are using BeautifulSoup and therefore locks you out with a 403.

Comment: ok how would i authenticate it then ?